# How do I combine (merge) two scales?

Tags: pca, scales, composite

I mesured two constructs,  intention to book a room (4 items) and intention to book from a web site (3 items), (Pearson correlation = 0.344**) I've been asked by a reviwer to merge the two scales. Please tell me what's the right way to do that! (both come from the same questionnaire) Factorial analysis of the 7 items at time showed One factor with 60.6 cumulative var
thanks

Comment: Try pca. Use first component. If FA  succesful then it should works.

Comment: This answer is of general type and discusses politics of merging scales/items https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/260682/3277

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Manually merge them. E.g., NewVariable = average(Variable 1, Variable 2, ...)
2. Save the factor/component from a PCA/Factor analysis.
3. If estimating a SEM of some kind, change the setup of the model so that it assumes a single latent variable.