# Can I convert the feature values of a new observation into factor values given a prior factor analysis?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I'm pretty new to factor analysis, but am able to go through the basic process including doing the initial analysis, getting the varimax rotation, and pca scores for each observation in R. In my specific case, I am reducing 16 features into 3 factors.

However, if I wanted to look at a new observation (i.e., not one in which I conducted the initial analysis) with the aforementioned 16 features, how could I get its values in terms of the 3 factors obtained in the earlier analysis? TIA

Comment: To compute factor/component scores for old or for new data we use factor score coefficient matrix which is a function of the loadings. Overview: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/126885/3277

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the factor values for a new observation. You need to use the loadings matrix. Consider the following example using the `food` dataset (it has 5 features, which rely on 2 factors):

```
> food <- read.csv("https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/soga/300/30100_data_sets/food-texture.csv", row.names = "X")
> food.fa <- factanal(food, factors = 2)
> food.fa$loadings

Loadings:
         Factor1 Factor2
Oil      -0.816         
Density   0.919         
Crispy   -0.745   0.635 
Fracture  0.645  -0.573 
Hardness          0.764 

               Factor1 Factor2
SS loadings      2.490   1.316
Proportion Var   0.498   0.263
Cumulative Var   0.498   0.761
```

Now let `x <- rep(1, 5)` be our new sample. In order to get the factor values, we simply multiply it with the loadings matrix:

```
> x <- rep(1,5)
> x %*% (food.fa$loadings)
       Factor1   Factor2
[1,] 0.1023468 0.8296464
```

Comment: Although your example seems to give logical answers for your example I am getting nonsensical ones in my case. I would appreciate your feedback based on the output below.

Comment: which output do you refer to?

Comment: The example works, but I am getting loadings that make no sense, perhaps due to the last command. I would appreciate your feedback based on this abbreviated code. >fit$loadings
Loadings:
               Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
ampl            0.232           0.906 
amplSD         -0.174           0.936 
...
               Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
SS loadings      3.970   2.686   1.963
Proportion Var   0.248   0.168   0.123...
> ex.features
 [1] 6.94e-02 6.89 ...
> ex.features %*% (fit$loadings)
      Factor1  Factor2  Factor3
[1,] 5850.236 2475.226 24.49456 (values too high!)

Comment: I cannot read this. please add it as an edit to your post and format as code.

Comment: I cannot format code+Rstudio output. Code is in {}, output is everything else: {ex.features} [1] 6.948084e-02 6.890209e-02 3.152680e+02 4.285756e+02 1.000853e-01 1.027555e-01 7.253998e+00 5.539933e+00
 [9] 1.099967e+03 1.882548e+03 2.248258e+02 6.636951e+01 1.933375e+01 3.684684e+00 2.458555e+03 1.879186e+03 {fit$loadings} Loadings:
               Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
ampl            0.232           0.906 
amplSD         -0.174           0.936 ...
(Note: 16 features, 3 factors)  {ex.features %*% (fit$loadings)}       Factor1  Factor2  Factor3
[1,] 5850.236 2475.226 24.49456

Comment: Hi can you help me please?